# How do I get the session ID of the connecting client in a socket.io python server?

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I have something like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

and:

```
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/rv')
def connect():
# want to get session id or some client identifier
```

because I want to send back to a specific client with emit and/or send?

Can someone show me how to get the right session/client identifier and then how to use it to send/emit a message back?

Comment: request.sid gives you the session ID, but how do you call emit/send on just this sesssion?

Answer (score 4):

At version 1.x and higher you can use `request.sid` to achieve the session ID.
Use `emit()` with the argument `room=session_id` to emit to a specific client.

Answer (score 1):

This post is old, but here's for newcomers:

The [documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_socketio.SocketIO.emit) of the `emit` function:

> to – **Send the message to** all the users in the given room, **or to the user with the given session ID**. If this parameter is not included, the event is sent to all connected users.

Use

```py
@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/rv')
def connect():
  session_id = request.sid # as in the older answer
  socketio.emit("some_event", "Only seen to the client who just connected", to=session_id)
  # the "to" argument sends the emit to the client who connected
```