# Flask-Socket.IO check which user disconnected

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I am trying to use the disconnect event in flask-socket.io:

```
@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    #some stuff
```

How do I get info on the user that disconnected?
I saw a solution in the JavaScript socket.io but I can't find solutions to this problem in python flask-socket.io

Comment: Are you creating a user in a database with your on.('connect') function? What info are you looking for exactly?

Comment: I could, I just want a way to know who disconnected, If that involves creating a user database I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There are some global variables that SocketIO sets upon each request received.](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#access-to-flask-s-context-globals)

- The `request` context global variable shows data about the current request being handled, [including their session id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49267961/7586861)
- The `session` context global variable has session-related information

The data these variables provide, however, is short lived. The session id means nothing after the user disconnects because when they connect again, they get a new session id unrelated to the last one. You won't be able to use the info to track when a user who has recently disconnected reconnects again. For that, you would need to handle that in a user database, for example. Using a login functionality would satisfy that.

The best way to explore what these global variables contain is to experiment.

Print out all the functions and attributes of the variables inside your connect or disconnect function:

```
from flask_socketio import request, session

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect():
    print("Request:")
    vars(request)
    dir(request)
    print("Session:")
    vars(session)
    dir(session)
```